# How do I scrape the HTML code from a webpage as it is using beautifulsoup without losing text format?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, web-scraping

I'm scraping some data from this website [enter link description here](http://www.keylessonline.com/song/tamil/karn/YammaYamma_7AmArivu.html)

After scraping the page, this is the html code I get

```
<div class=\"feature\">\n<p><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\n\n<html lang=\"Tamil\" style=\"direction: ltr;\"><head><!-- saved from url=(0067)http://www.keylessonline.com/notes/tamil/karn/raasaaththi-onna.html -->\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"/>\n<meta content=\"MSHTML 6.00.2900.2802\" name=\"GENERATOR\"/>\n<title>Carnatic Notes and Chords for \"Yamma Yamma\" (7Am Arivu)</title><meta content=\"VK\" name=\"author\"/></head>\n<body>\n<span style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Language : Tamil </span><br style=\"font-family: monospace;\"/>\n<span style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Song     : Yamma Yamma</span><br style=\"font-family: monospace;\"/>\n<span style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Movie    : 7Am Arivu</span><br style=\"font-family: monospace;\"/>\n<span style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Defaults : s r2 g3 m1 p d1 n2 (See </span><a href=\"http://www.keylessonline.com/legend.php\" style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Legend</a><span style=\"font-family: monospace;\"> for more\ndetails) </span><br style=\"font-family: monospace;\"/>\n<span style=\"font-family: monospace;\">Scale/Key: </span><span style=\"font-style: italic; font-family: monospace;\">C (Orig:D, Transpose:+2)</span><span style=\"font-family: monospace;\"></span><span style=\"font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; font-family: monospace;\"></span><span style=\"font-style: italic; font-family: monospace;\"></span><span style=\"font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; font-family: monospace;\"></span><span style=\"font-family: monospace;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;\"></span><br/><br/><span style=\"font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;\">Pallavi</span><br/>Yammaa Yammaa Kaadhal Ponnammaa Nee Enna  Vittu Ponadhennammaa<br/> \n   .                \n                 .<br/>P  P~S N  D   P  DP   M  G  M   P   P P~S N  D  P DPM   G  M<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">C\n                   \n      Fm      C      \n               Fm<br/><br/></span>NenjukkuLLe Kaayam Aachammaa En Pattaam Poochi Saayam POchammaa<br/>   .                                 .<br/>P\n S  N  D  P  DP  M G   M   P\n P  P~S  N  D   P  DP  M G   M<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">C\n                   \n   Fm     C          \n                Fm</span><br/><br/>Adi AaNOda Kaadhal Kai Rega POla PeNNOda Kaadhal Kai Kutta POla<br/>SR\n R~MMM  M  M~P  G   G M  GRS  M\n M M  M  M~P  G   G  M  GRS<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"> \n  Fm             C    \n        Fm          \n   C</span><br/><br/>KanavukkuLLe AvaLa Vechchenae En KaNNa ReNda Thirudi POnaaLe<br/>p p G2 G2 R  SS R  S   n3 S~R n3 n3 n3 n3 S  R  R R  G2R  S<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">Cm\n                   \n   G                \n              Cm</span><br/><br/>Pullaanguzhala Kaiyil ThandhaaLae En Moochuk Kaatha Vaangi POnaaLae<br/>p  p~G2G2G2 R  S  R   S   n3  S~R n3 n3 n3   n3 S   R   R  G2R  S<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">Cm\n                   \n       G            \n                    Cm</span><br/><br/><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Charanam 1</span></span><br/>Pombalaiya Nambi Kettuponavanga Romba<br/>G  G G  M  M~PP  P  M G G G  M  M~PP<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">C</span><br/><br/>Andha Varisaiyil Naanum Ippa Kadaisiyil Ninnaen<br/>P P   P D D  P   P~MM   M P  G R  G R   G~RR<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">      Fm                     G</span><br/><br/>Muththedukka POnaal Unn Moochadangum Thannaal<br/>G   G  G  M  M~PP   P~M G  G  G  M   M~P P<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">C</span><br/><br/>Kaadhal Muththeduththa Pinnaal Manam Piththamaagum PeNNaal<br/>P  P    P   D  D   P   P~MM    M P   G   R  G  R   G~RR<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">        Fm                           G</span><br/><br/>Ava Kaiyavittuthaan POyaachuuuu Kannu ReNdumae Poiyyaachu<br/>SR  R~MM M  M M     GRGR S~~R   R~MM  M  M M   GR  GR RS<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"> \n  Fm              C  \n        Fm          \n  C</span><br/><br/>Kaadhal Enbadhu VeeN Paechu Manam Unnalae PuNNaai POchu<br/>R~MM    M M M   GR   GR S   S S   n3S RS  n3 d    p m<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">Fm              C                 G</span><br/><br/>Kaadhal Paadha Kallu MuLLuda Adha KadanthupOna AaLae Illadaa<br/>p  p~G2 G2 G2R S  R  S  n3SR RS   n3n3 n3 n3S  R R   MGR S<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">Cm\n                   \n   G                \n             Cm</span><br/><br/>Kaadhal Oru BOdha Maathira Adha POttukitta Moongil Yaathirai<br/>p  p~G2 G2R S R   S  n3 SR RS   n3 n3n3 S  R   R   MG R  S<br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\">Cm\n                   \n G                  \n             C</span><br/><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"></span></span>\n</body></html>\n</p>\n</div>
```

Which gives me the following output:
[image: Output from scraped html]

But this is the HTML code I get from the webpage manually when I use dev tools and select copy->inner.HTML:

```
<p>
<!-- saved from url=(0067)http://www.keylessonline.com/notes/tamil/karn/raasaaththi-onna.html -->

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <meta content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.2802" name="GENERATOR">

  <title>Carnatic Notes and Chords for "Yamma Yamma" (7Am Arivu)</title><meta content="VK" name="author">

<span style="font-family: monospace;">Language : Tamil </span><br style="font-family: monospace;">
<span style="font-family: monospace;">Song&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : Yamma Yamma</span><br style="font-family: monospace;">
<span style="font-family: monospace;">Movie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : 7Am Arivu</span><br style="font-family: monospace;">
<span style="font-family: monospace;">Defaults : s r2 g3 m1 p d1 n2 (See </span><a style="font-family: monospace;" href="http://www.keylessonline.com/legend.php">Legend</a><span style="font-family: monospace;"> for more
details) </span><br style="font-family: monospace;">
<span style="font-family: monospace;">Scale/Key: </span><span style="font-style: italic; font-family: monospace;">C (Orig:D, Transpose:+2)</span><span style="font-family: monospace;"></span><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; font-family: monospace;"></span><span style="font-style: italic; font-family: monospace;"></span><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; font-family: monospace;"></span><span style="font-family: monospace;"><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;"></span><br><br><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Pallavi</span><br>Yammaa Yammaa Kaadhal Ponnammaa Nee Enna &nbsp;Vittu Ponadhennammaa<br>&nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.<br>P &nbsp;P~S N &nbsp;D &nbsp; P &nbsp;DP &nbsp; M &nbsp;G &nbsp;M &nbsp; P &nbsp; P P~S N &nbsp;D &nbsp;P DPM &nbsp; G &nbsp;M<br><span style="font-style: italic;">C
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Fm<br><br></span>NenjukkuLLe Kaayam Aachammaa En Pattaam Poochi Saayam POchammaa<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; .<br>P
&nbsp;S &nbsp;N &nbsp;D &nbsp;P &nbsp;DP &nbsp;M G &nbsp; M &nbsp; P
&nbsp;P &nbsp;P~S &nbsp;N &nbsp;D &nbsp; P &nbsp;DP &nbsp;M G &nbsp; M<br><span style="font-style: italic;">C
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; C &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm</span><br><br>Adi AaNOda Kaadhal Kai Rega POla PeNNOda Kaadhal Kai Kutta POla<br>SR
&nbsp;R~MMM &nbsp;M &nbsp;M~P &nbsp;G &nbsp; G M &nbsp;GRS &nbsp;M
&nbsp;M M &nbsp;M &nbsp;M~P &nbsp;G &nbsp; G &nbsp;M &nbsp;GRS<br><span style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp;
&nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; C &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;C</span><br><br>KanavukkuLLe AvaLa Vechchenae En KaNNa ReNda Thirudi POnaaLe<br>p p G2 G2 R &nbsp;SS R &nbsp;S &nbsp; n3 S~R n3 n3 n3 n3 S &nbsp;R &nbsp;R R &nbsp;G2R &nbsp;S<br><span style="font-style: italic;">Cm
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;G &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cm</span><br><br>Pullaanguzhala Kaiyil ThandhaaLae En Moochuk Kaatha Vaangi POnaaLae<br>p &nbsp;p~G2G2G2 R &nbsp;S &nbsp;R &nbsp; S &nbsp; n3 &nbsp;S~R n3 n3 n3 &nbsp; n3 S &nbsp; R &nbsp; R &nbsp;G2R &nbsp;S<br><span style="font-style: italic;">Cm
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;G &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cm</span><br><br><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Charanam 1</span></span><br>Pombalaiya Nambi Kettuponavanga Romba<br>G &nbsp;G G &nbsp;M &nbsp;M~PP &nbsp;P &nbsp;M G G G &nbsp;M &nbsp;M~PP<br><span style="font-style: italic;">C</span><br><br>Andha Varisaiyil Naanum Ippa Kadaisiyil Ninnaen<br>P P &nbsp; P D D &nbsp;P &nbsp; P~MM &nbsp; M P &nbsp;G R &nbsp;G R &nbsp; G~RR<br><span style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; G</span><br><br>Muththedukka POnaal Unn Moochadangum Thannaal<br>G &nbsp; G &nbsp;G &nbsp;M &nbsp;M~PP &nbsp; P~M G &nbsp;G &nbsp;G &nbsp;M &nbsp; M~P P<br><span style="font-style: italic;">C</span><br><br>Kaadhal Muththeduththa Pinnaal Manam Piththamaagum PeNNaal<br>P &nbsp;P &nbsp; &nbsp;P &nbsp; D &nbsp;D &nbsp; P &nbsp; P~MM &nbsp; &nbsp;M P &nbsp; G &nbsp; R &nbsp;G &nbsp;R &nbsp; G~RR<br><span style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; G</span><br><br>Ava Kaiyavittuthaan POyaachuuuu Kannu ReNdumae Poiyyaachu<br>SR &nbsp;R~MM M &nbsp;M M &nbsp; &nbsp; GRGR S~~R &nbsp; R~MM &nbsp;M &nbsp;M M&nbsp; &nbsp;GR &nbsp;GR RS<br><span style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp;
&nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; C</span><br><br>Kaadhal Enbadhu VeeN Paechu Manam Unnalae PuNNaai POchu<br>R~MM &nbsp; &nbsp;M M M &nbsp; GR &nbsp; GR S &nbsp; S S &nbsp; n3S RS &nbsp;n3 d&nbsp; &nbsp; p m<br><span style="font-style: italic;">Fm &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; G</span><br><br>Kaadhal Paadha Kallu MuLLuda Adha KadanthupOna AaLae Illadaa<br>p &nbsp;p~G2 G2 G2R S &nbsp;R &nbsp;S &nbsp;n3SR RS &nbsp; n3n3 n3 n3S &nbsp;R R &nbsp; MGR S<br><span style="font-style: italic;">Cm
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp;G &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Cm</span><br><br>Kaadhal Oru BOdha Maathira Adha POttukitta Moongil Yaathirai<br>p &nbsp;p~G2 G2R S R &nbsp; S &nbsp;n3 SR RS &nbsp; n3 n3n3 S &nbsp;R &nbsp; R &nbsp; MG R &nbsp;S<br><span style="font-style: italic;">Cm
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp;G &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C</span><br><span style="font-style: italic;"></span></span>

    </p>
```

Which gives me the following output :
[image: Original HTML code]

Note how the format of the text changes. The spacing is proper in the original one, but not in my scraped one.

I want to get the HTML code of the later by scraping using BS4 ( the one I get by manually selecting inner.HTML from dev tools).

How do I do that?

This is my python script:

```
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
import json
from bs4.element import Comment

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer




response = requests.get('http://www.keylessonline.com/list/tamil')

src = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
songList=[]
baseurl = "http://www.keylessonline.com"



song_links=[]
songNames=[]
test=[]
songFullLinks=[]
songFullNames=[]
for names in soup.select('.songname'):
        songNames.append(names.get_text())

links = soup.select("a[href*=karn]")
#Creates  a csv file and stores a column of name of song and links to every song
with open('Name_Links.csv','w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer=writer(csv_file)
    headers=['Song Name:','Song Link']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)
    for link in links:

        if "View" in link.text:
            song_links=link.attrs["href"]       
            if(song_links.find('Details') == -1):
                songList=baseurl+song_links
                songFullLinks += [songList]
               # test+=[song_links] This works too... Dont use append


                if(song_links.find('/song/tamil/karn/')>-1):

                    removeHTML = re.sub(".html","",song_links)
                    removehtm = re.sub(".htm","",removeHTML)
                    removeSongTamilKarn = re.sub("/song/tamil/karn/","",removehtm)
                    removeDetails =re.sub("_Details","", removeSongTamilKarn)
                    songNameList = removeDetails
                    songFullNames+=[songNameList]
                    songInfo = [songNameList,songList]
                    csv_writer.writerow(songInfo)



#This is the code that you should be looking at ..Above this is experimenting with different stuff
#Iterates through each link and scrapes the html part from the class "feature"
with open('Names_Notes.csv','w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer=writer(csv_file)
        headers=['Song Name:','Song Notes']
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)
        i=0
        for name in songFullNames:
            print(name)


        for songsURL in songFullLinks:

            responseURL = requests.get(songsURL)
            srcURL = responseURL.content
            soupURL = BeautifulSoup(srcURL,'lxml')
            note=soupURL.select('.feature')

            nameNotes = [songFullNames[i],note]
            csv_writer.writerow(nameNotes)
            i=i+1
```

**UPDATE**

After trying out this code by user Andrej

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.keylessonline.com/song/tamil/karn/YammaYamma_7AmArivu.html'
t = requests.get(url).text

t = re.sub(r'&nbsp;', '#', t)   # <- replace all &nbsp; with '#'
t = re.sub(r'\n', ' ', t)

soup = BeautifulSoup( t, 'html5lib' )
soup.select_one('#content title').extract()
for br in soup.select('#content br'):
    br.replace_with('|')        # <- replace all <br> with '|'

text = soup.select_one('#content').get_text().replace('\n', '').replace('#', ' ').replace('|', '\n').strip()
print(re.sub(r'^\s+([A-Z].*?:)', r'\1', text, flags=re.M))
```

I do get the same output in the terminal . Which is nice. But , I want to display the same output in a HTML file (Actually react app, right now testing through html)

The HTML code simply this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contents">


        <div id="notes"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("notes").innerText=`The Song Notes from python script goes here`</script>



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Upon copy pasting the output from terminal to inside of innerText tag I get the following result :

```
Language : Tamil
Song : Yamma Yamma
Movie : 7Am Arivu
Defaults : s r2 g3 m1 p d1 n2 (See Legend for more details)
Scale/Key: C (Orig:D, Transpose:+2)

Pallavi
Yammaa Yammaa Kaadhal Ponnammaa Nee Enna Vittu Ponadhennammaa
. .
P P~S N D P DP M G M P P P~S N D P DPM G M
C Fm C Fm

NenjukkuLLe Kaayam Aachammaa En Pattaam Poochi Saayam POchammaa
. .
P S N D P DP M G M P P P~S N D P DP M G M
C Fm C Fm

Adi AaNOda Kaadhal Kai Rega POla PeNNOda Kaadhal Kai Kutta POla
SR R~MMM M M~P G G M GRS M M M M M~P G G M GRS
Fm C Fm C

KanavukkuLLe AvaLa Vechchenae En KaNNa ReNda Thirudi POnaaLe
p p G2 G2 R SS R S n3 S~R n3 n3 n3 n3 S R R R G2R S
Cm G Cm

Pullaanguzhala Kaiyil ThandhaaLae En Moochuk Kaatha Vaangi POnaaLae
p p~G2G2G2 R S R S n3 S~R n3 n3 n3 n3 S R R G2R S
Cm G Cm

Charanam 1
Pombalaiya Nambi Kettuponavanga Romba
G G G M M~PP P M G G G M M~PP
C

Andha Varisaiyil Naanum Ippa Kadaisiyil Ninnaen
P P P D D P P~MM M P G R G R G~RR
Fm G

Muththedukka POnaal Unn Moochadangum Thannaal
G G G M M~PP P~M G G G M M~P P
C

Kaadhal Muththeduththa Pinnaal Manam Piththamaagum PeNNaal
P P P D D P P~MM M P G R G R G~RR
Fm G

Ava Kaiyavittuthaan POyaachuuuu Kannu ReNdumae Poiyyaachu
SR R~MM M M M GRGR S~~R R~MM M M M GR GR RS
Fm C Fm C

Kaadhal Enbadhu VeeN Paechu Manam Unnalae PuNNaai POchu
R~MM M M M GR GR S S S n3S RS n3 d p m
Fm C G

Kaadhal Paadha Kallu MuLLuda Adha KadanthupOna AaLae Illadaa
p p~G2 G2 G2R S R S n3SR RS n3n3 n3 n3S R R MGR S
Cm G Cm

Kaadhal Oru BOdha Maathira Adha POttukitta Moongil Yaathirai
p p~G2 G2R S R S n3 SR RS n3 n3n3 S R R MG R S
Cm G C
```

You see, the notes under lyrics aren't properly formatted .
I tried using innerHTML and did'nt replace 
 tag but then I get '#' instead of spaces. To get rid of that I have to use get_text() , Which removes the HTML tags.

How shall I solve this now?

**Update: Solved**

The answer solves it for me.
It gives me the html code I needed.

Also, to display text while maintaining formatting , I discovered that I just have to wrap the text around  this tag

Thank you for the help guys.

Comment: Is the content the same, is this purely visual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that tries to keep the original formatting:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.keylessonline.com/song/tamil/karn/YammaYamma_7AmArivu.html'
t = requests.get(url).text

t = re.sub(r'&nbsp;', '#', t)   # <- replace all &nbsp; with '#'
t = re.sub(r'\n', ' ', t)

soup = BeautifulSoup( t, 'html5lib' )
title = soup.select_one('#content title, #content tt')
if title:
    title.extract()
for br in soup.select('#content br'):
    br.replace_with('|')        # <- replace all <br> with '|'

text = soup.select_one('#content').get_text().replace('\n', '').replace('#', ' ').replace('|', '\n').strip()
text = re.sub(r'^\s+([A-Z].*?:)', r'\1', text, flags=re.M)
print('<pre>' + text + '</pre>')
```

Prints:

```
<pre>Language : Tamil 
Song     : Yamma Yamma
Movie    : 7Am Arivu
Defaults : s r2 g3 m1 p d1 n2 (See Legend for more details) 
Scale/Key: C (Orig:D, Transpose:+2)

Pallavi
Yammaa Yammaa Kaadhal Ponnammaa Nee Enna  Vittu Ponadhennammaa
     .                                  .
P  P~S N  D   P  DP   M  G  M   P   P P~S N  D  P DPM   G  M
C                           Fm      C                      Fm

NenjukkuLLe Kaayam Aachammaa En Pattaam Poochi Saayam POchammaa
   .                                 .
P  S  N  D  P  DP  M G   M   P  P  P~S  N  D   P  DP  M G   M
C                        Fm     C                           Fm

Adi AaNOda Kaadhal Kai Rega POla PeNNOda Kaadhal Kai Kutta POla
SR  R~MMM  M  M~P  G   G M  GRS  M  M M  M  M~P  G   G  M  GRS
    Fm             C             Fm              C

KanavukkuLLe AvaLa Vechchenae En KaNNa ReNda Thirudi POnaaLe
p p G2 G2 R  SS R  S   n3 S~R n3 n3 n3 n3 S  R  R R  G2R  S
Cm                        G                               Cm

Pullaanguzhala Kaiyil ThandhaaLae En Moochuk Kaatha Vaangi POnaaLae
p  p~G2G2G2 R  S  R   S   n3  S~R n3 n3 n3   n3 S   R   R  G2R  S
Cm                            G                                 Cm

Charanam 1
Pombalaiya Nambi Kettuponavanga Romba
G  G G  M  M~PP  P  M G G G  M  M~PP
C

Andha Varisaiyil Naanum Ippa Kadaisiyil Ninnaen
P P   P D D  P   P~MM   M P  G R  G R   G~RR
      Fm                     G

Muththedukka POnaal Unn Moochadangum Thannaal
G   G  G  M  M~PP   P~M G  G  G  M   M~P P
C

Kaadhal Muththeduththa Pinnaal Manam Piththamaagum PeNNaal
P  P    P   D  D   P   P~MM    M P   G   R  G  R   G~RR
        Fm                           G

Ava Kaiyavittuthaan POyaachuuuu Kannu ReNdumae Poiyyaachu
SR  R~MM M  M M     GRGR S~~R   R~MM  M  M M   GR  GR RS
    Fm              C           Fm             C

Kaadhal Enbadhu VeeN Paechu Manam Unnalae PuNNaai POchu
R~MM    M M M   GR   GR S   S S   n3S RS  n3 d    p m
Fm              C                 G

Kaadhal Paadha Kallu MuLLuda Adha KadanthupOna AaLae Illadaa
p  p~G2 G2 G2R S  R  S  n3SR RS   n3n3 n3 n3S  R R   MGR S
Cm                        G                              Cm

Kaadhal Oru BOdha Maathira Adha POttukitta Moongil Yaathirai
p  p~G2 G2R S R   S  n3 SR RS   n3 n3n3 S  R   R   MG R  S
Cm                      G                                C</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  On implying the above method , the formatting works perfectly well.

But when I store this as json and copy paste from json to html...It doesn't display with the same formatting.

Also, if I copy paste from the terminal output to html. It does'nt display properly.
How do I store it in a way so that I can display it properly in a html page

Comment: Your solution was excellent , thank you taking the time. I had to enclose the output text in a <pre> tag to get it working

Comment: Yep , works as I wanted now , but the catch here is , the code crashes after executing the 4th link . As the the webpage in the 4th link does not have 'title' instead uses 'tt' .

How can we make it search for title | tt ?

Comment: Hey, can I have an update on this please? How will be able to choose for 'title' OR 'tt'

Comment: @harikrishnan Before the `.extract()` there is `title = soup.select_one('#content title, #content tt')`. In `title` variable you have title or tt.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I was trying the OR operator instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use prettify(formatter="html") can help you :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://www.keylessonline.com/song/tamil/karn/YammaYamma_7AmArivu.html')
src = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
print(soup.find("div", {"class": "feature"}).prettify(formatter="html"))
```

Comment: Thank you this solved it for me, I wanted the exact HTML code and just display it on a page.